# What does JoinableQueue.join() Block?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

The documentation for [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) says

> **join()** Block until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed

I know that when I call `Process.join()` or `Thread.join()`, the execution of the current process or thread is stopped until the process or thread who's join method I called exits.

The documentation for [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) uses the same language as that for `JoinableQueue`

> **join([timeout])** Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

Can I always understand "block" to refer to pausing the calling thread until some condition has been met? I can't find any confirmation in the documentation. If I search for "block python", I only find information about blocks of code or the same documentation I quote above.

Comment: *Can I always understand "block" to refer to pausing the calling thread until some condition has been met?* In the context of multi-threading/multi-processing in python, almost always: yes.

Comment: @jedwards Great! And `JoinableQueue` falls into multi-threading/multi-processing in python, I assume.

Comment: Indeed it does -- look at [its package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) :)

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407589/what-does-the-term-blocking-mean-in-programming) for a more generic question about the meaning of blocking. It's a term used across all of software development, not just in Python.

Comment: @dano that's a good link, I didn't mean to suggest that blocking was only used in python, just that within that context, OP would be safe to associate that meaning with the term.  I can't speak about how other languages decide to use it, if they decide to use it differently (which of course would be weird and confusing) -- but this was the reason for my qualification.  Sorry if it was misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's docs are using "blocked" (and other forms of the same stem "block") in the classical sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state -- any thread (or process) can be "running", or "ready" (but waiting for a CPU), or "blocked" (and then "terminated" once it is, essentially, finished).

(In CPython in particular, within a given process, only one thread can be "running" *Python* code no matter how many CPUs are available -- others which are in the abstract sense "ready" are in fact internally blocked by the Global Interpreter Lock aka GIL -- but, that's an implementation detail and only applies to certain implementations, not to Python as a **language**).