# What does "block" mean in javadoc

Tags: java, multithreading, java-io, blocking

I was reading the Java API Document in Eclipse for

```
int java.io.FileInputStream.read(byte[] b) throws IOException
```

and found the following explanation:

"Reads up to b.length bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes. This method **blocks** until some input is available."

What does *block* actually mean here? From my English knowledge, *block* is a *transitive verb*, which means it has to have an object following it... But here, it works like a *intransitive verb*....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407589/what-does-the-term-blocking-mean-in-programming